# frameworks for outdoor image-processing in augmented-reality context?

Tags: android, image-processing, frameworks, augmented-reality

I'm planning to write my bachelor thesis about augmented reality. I want to build an application, which can take images, mark objects inside of them, and give the user the possibility, to show the marked objects later, when for example, the object doesn't exist in real life anymore (so the user can start the camera and i project the object into the scenario) Therefore i have to check, if something similar already exists - I've seen a lot of frameworks doing stuff with qr-codes or giving information to existing objects inside of the application, but i couldn't find an existing application for my specific case.

Do you know if something similar already exists? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean with "mark objects inside the images". What kind of objects do you mean?

For marker based AR you have several Frameworks. [Vuforia](http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality) is really a good one, and quite easy to use. The new Cloud AR, consisting in looking for markers in the Cloud, may be relevant to you.
Another option could be [metaio](http://www.metaio.com/)

For marker-less tracking, I don't know of any Framework implementing that yet. If you want to make something for your own, I guess Monocular SLAM might be quite relevant. But it may get quite complicated. Basically it works like [that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXsgB6lRt64).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! Well, i mean the following: For example, i take a picture of a car (with buildings in the background and other stuff on the left/right side of the car). I will mark the car and later, if the car is away, i will project it into the scene (by using image processing or other functions from the smartphone(gps, bearing)

Comment: What do you want to project exactly? a static image of the car? Or a 3d model of some car you will have somewhere? It's not trivial to get a 3d model out of a set of images, specially with buildings and stuff around. And if you want to make it work for every object, I'm not sure that's possible, specially if it is for your bachelor thesis :)
Anyway, GPS augmented reality alone is possible to implement. You can take a look at Layar or Wikitude. But they just augment static images or 3d models you have on a database.

Comment: I will use a static image of the car and i'm trying to project it into the scene (at exact the position, the car was when i took the picture)

Comment: But when you rotate around you will need much more than a static image. For similar position/bearing you can maybe interpolate the image, but what are you going to do if you are on the other side of your object?
Another thing is how you are going to isolate your object in the image. That's a normal problem if you know what are you looking for and you have some samples of it, but how do you know what you need to isolate?

Comment: Well, when i'm on the other side of the object, i don't have to project it ;)  - and for the isolation: There exists already an application, which can take pictures and isolate the desired object (i'll work with that application). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just for curiosity, could you tell what is this application? :) If it's not something private/intern to your company/uni I mean.
Given your requirements, you could save the position and rotation when you take the picture, isolate your object, and later use the current pose to augment it.